# What do you think (of/about) the service?

Tags: word-choice

If I wanted to know the opinions of people about the quality of service in the context of  hotels/banks/restaurants, what should I use: "think of" or "think about"?

According to my Google search:

> What do you think about the service?

is more common than:

> What do you think of the service?

At first I thought "think of" is more fitting because that is how I used to ask about people's opinions, but now I am not sure anymore!

Does it matter when you ask people about the service **in general**, and when you ask them about an **instance** of the service, I mean, a particular occasion?

Have a look at "**[think of sth/sb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/think-of-sth-sb)**" from Cambridge's Dictionary

**to have a good opinion of someone or something:**

> She thinks very highly of her boss.

This one is related too [think of/about sb/sth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/think-of-about-sb-sth)

Comment: It could be a duplicate, but I have already checked J.R.'s answer and could relate the point here. I have read a couple of posts on the Web, and then said it is better to get a specific answer.

Comment: Tough break; I missed "not" in "and could not relate the point here" in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Either are acceptable. I am not familiar with any difference between *think of* and *think about*, either in their formal meanings, or in their contextual or regional usage.

I would use *think of*, but that's merely personal preference.

> Does it matter when you ask people about the service in general, and when you ask them about an instance of the service, I mean, a particular occasion?

If you want to get in the nuances of this, you should be more specific in your question, e.g.:

> What do you think of the service you have received the last time you stayed at The Glitz-Glamorton Hotel?

vs.

> What do you think of the service you have received during your stays at The Glitz-Glamorton Hotel?

Be aware that survey responses (whether you are conducting a formal survey or just asking someone informally of their opinion) are highly influenced by the form of the question. If you want the response to be open-ended, *think of* or *think about* are probably good phrases to use. If you are looking for a specific aspect, mention that in your question, and use another phrase besides *think of* or *think about*:

> How would you rate the service you have received the last time you stayed at The Glitz-Glamorton Hotel?
>
> Were you satisfied with your recent stay at The Glitz-Glamorton Hotel?
>
> Did the staff at The Glitz-Glamorton Hotel meet your needs during your recent stay?
>
> Was the staff at The Glitz-Glamorton Hotel courteous and friendly during your recent stay?
>
> Based on your recent stay at The Glitz-Glamorton Hotel, is there anything you would recommend we try to improve?