# Just thinking of/about the smell makes me want to throw up!

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Someone was talking about cats and I said I'm not a pet person mainly because of their poops. Then I said:
"Just thinking **about** the smell makes me want to throw up."

Even though I said 'about' I feel like I should have said 'of' since thinking about means actively thinking about something and thinking of means you are least aware about it/an idea comes to your mind.

Since I don't actively think about cat poops. Should I have said 'of?'

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Think of" versus "think about"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9383/think-of-versus-think-about) Also [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239592/think-of-about-something-or-thinking-someone) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39023/what-do-you-think-of-about-the-service)

Comment: Thank you. I think it does even though I'm not completely sure. According to the post it should be 'think of.' Think about sounds awkward to me. I mean why would I think about the smell of cat poop which I hate so much!